# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 not working with typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

The problem occurs when using input-group css class.
The text box appears as if it were cut.

Typeahead works but the design is displayed erroneously:

[image]

The idea is not to apply more css format to the control. Use the one that comes by default.

Answer (score -2):

I have solved the problem by adding 100% style to the width of the control while solving the problem natively, because it is not the idea to add more css code.
Thank you.

[Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAqXh.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0pMN.png)